# jQuery : How to Select input fields which are displayed in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I came across a situation, where I want to select the input elements which are not hidden and visible in other nav-tabs.

I am using the following code to select the input fields

```
$("input[type!=hidden]").each(function(){
        ......
    });
```

But, it selects the input fields which are hidden using **jQuery.hide()** function, i.e. visibility none. Here I'm hiding the parents of input elements i.e.

If I try to filter again with visibility property, jQuery treated the input elements in **inactive(non-current) nav tabs as invisible**. So, inactive tabs' input fields are not selected.

```
$("input[type!=hidden]").filter(:visible).each(function(){
            ......
        });
```

How to select input fields in this scenario?

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $("#three").hide();  //Hiding div element
      
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("input:not([type='hidden'])").each(function(){
                $(this).val("2");
            });
          $("#output").html("Output: " + $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#four").val());
        });
    });
    </script>

    <html>
      <body>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-contents">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="first" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="one" type="text" value="1"><br>    
        <button>Test</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="second" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="two" type="text" value="1"><br>
        <div id="three">
          <input id="four" type="text" value="1"> 
        </div>   
      </div>
     </div>
        Answer Should be : 221  (It should not change the hidden value)
        <div id="output"></div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: try `$("input:not([type='hidden'])")`

Comment: @Banzay, it didn't work as it selects the input fields hidden by using jQuery .hide() function. bcoz their visibility:none

Comment: can u add the html structure?

Comment: @SuhailAKhtar, Edited the post to add code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between `jquery.hide()` being applied to an `input` & a `<input type="hidden">`

- What `jquery.hide()` does is it just sets the `display` property of the `input` element as `none`.
- What `$("input[type='hidden']")` does is it searches for all the input elements that have a `type` attribute whose value is `hidden`.

Hence, when you hide the `input` element or its parent, it does not affect the `type` attribute of the `input` element, it only sets the `display` property as `none`.

To get your code working, you have to manually modify the `type` attribute of the `input` element.

Refer code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#four").attr("type", "hidden");

  $("button").click(function() {
    $("input:not([type='hidden'])").each(function() {
      $(this).val("2");
    });
    $("#output").html("Output: " + $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#four").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-contents">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="first" role="tabpanel">
    <input id="one" type="text" value="1">
    <br>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="second" role="tabpanel">
    <input id="two" type="text" value="1">
    <br>
    <div id="three">
      <input id="four" type="text" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Answer Should be : 221 (It should not change the hidden value)
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yes @nashcheez, Your solution is very close to my expectation. I'll implement your solution. In actual scenario, I'm hiding <td> element of the table, which is parent of <input>, in future it may not be an immediate parent. So, please suggest me to change the attribute to hidden for that type of input.

Comment: What you can do in such a case is just change the code and put - `$("table td input").attr("type", "hidden");`. This will change the `type` attribute of all inputs inside a td irrespective of it being a direct parent or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) combined to a filter to get all the visible inputs:

```js
var visible = $('input:not(:hidden)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('visibility') != 'hidden';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden">-
<input style="display:none">-
<input style="visibility: hidden">-
<input>
```

Comment: it didn't work as it selects the input fields hidden by using jQuery .hide() function. bcoz their visibility:none

Comment: @Rajasekhar Updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $("#three").hide();  //Hiding div element
      
         $("button").click(function(){
       
            $("input").each(function(){

            if($(this).parent().attr("style") !== "display: none;" && $(this).attr("type") !== "hidden" ){
                $(this).val("2");
                }
            });
          $("#output").html("Output: " + $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#four").val());
        });

    });
    </script>

    <html>
      <body>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-contents">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="first" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="one" type="text" value="1"><br>    
        <button>Test</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="second" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="two" type="text" value="1"><br>
        <div id="three">
          <input id="four" type="text" value="1"> 
        </div>   
      </div>
     </div>
        Answer Should be : 221  (It should not change the hidden value)
        <div id="output"></div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Hope this one is helpfull

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $("#three").hide();  //Hiding div element
      
      $("button").click(function(){
      
        $("input").each(function() {
          if(this.type !== "hidden" && this.parentNode.style.display !== "none") {
            this.value = 2;
          }
        });

        $("#output").html("Output: " + $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() +$("#four").val());
      });
    });
    </script>

    <html>
      <body>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-contents">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="first" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="one" type="text" value="1"><br>    
        <button>Test</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="second" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="two" type="text" value="1"><br>
        <div id="three">
          <input id="four" type="text" value="1"> 
        </div>   
      </div>
     </div>
        Answer Should be : 221  (It should not change the hidden value)
        <div id="output"></div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Your solution is also very close to my scenario and I have implemented it in my program and working great. But, I'm looking for generic scenario and @nashcheez answered it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input:not([type='hidden'])").each(function(){
            $(this).css('background', "#ccc");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="hidden">
    <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work as it selects the input fields hidden by using jQuery .hide() function. bcoz their visibility:none

Comment: Then try this:
`$("input").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('type') == 'hidden'){
             //its hidden input
            } else{
             //not hidden
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

I've used your code, it works for me.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#three").hide();  //Hiding div element
  
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input:not([type='hidden'])").each(function(){
            $(this).val("2");
        });
      $("#output").html("Output: " + $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#four").val());
      console.log($("input[type='hidden']").val());
    });
  
  
    
});
</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
      </li>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-contents">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="first" role="tabpanel">    
    <input id="one" type="text" value="1"><br>    
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="second" role="tabpanel">    
    <input id="two" type="text" value="1"><br>
    <div id="three">
      <input id="four" type="text" value="1"> 
    </div>   
    <input type="hidden" value="123">
  </div>
 </div>
    Answer Should be : 221  (It should not change the hidden value)
    <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: See you are getting output as 222 instead of 221

Comment: Now I've got ur point. You want to exclude the input box having parent div hidden.. according to your question, I had excluded input type hidden as you can see: `$("input:not([type='hidden'])").each(function(){
    $(this).val("2");
});`

if you want to exclude the input which are not being shown on page, then use the second answer of mine and please upvote, if you find my answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Answer according to your requirement:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#three").hide();  //Hiding div element
  
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").each(function(){
          if($(this).closest('div').is(':visible')){
            $(this).val("2");
          }
        });
      $("#output").html("Output: " + $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#four").val());
    });
  
  
    
});
</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
      </li>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-contents">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="first" role="tabpanel">    
    <input id="one" type="text" value="1"><br>    
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="second" role="tabpanel">    
    <input id="two" type="text" value="1"><br>
    <div id="three">
      <input id="four" type="text" value="1"> 
    </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
    Answer Should be : 221  (It should not change the hidden value)
    <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have edited your code to include bootstrap. Now you can see the difference. Again my code is just an example. There may be so many div elements between the non active tab.

Answer (score 0):

This will select all elements visible from visible tab and those hidden only by the tab-pane. If the element creating the hidding effect is not a tab-pane it will be ignored.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $("#three").hide();  //Hiding div element
      
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("input:not([type='hidden'])").each(function(){
    var div = $(this).parent().closest(":hidden");
    if(div.length == 0 || div.hasClass("tab-pane")){
     $(this).val("2");
    }
    
            });
          $("#output").html("Output: " + $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() +$("#four").val());
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
      <body>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-contents">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="first" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="one" type="text" value="1"><br>    
        <button>Test</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="second" role="tabpanel">    
        <input id="two" type="text" value="1"><br>
        <div id="three">
          <input id="four" type="text" value="1"> 
        </div>   
      </div>
     </div>
        Answer Should be : 221  (It should not change the hidden value)
        <div id="output"></div>
        </body>
      </html>
```